# Apple in-app provisioning (add card to wallet)

Tags: swift, ios-provisioning, apple-wallet

I am implementing "add a card to the wallet" button and I am able to finish it but I have a problem identifying cards in the system... I need to add into pass some additional data like customer id or whatever and I found [userInfo in apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpass/1618794-userinfo)

and I played with that but I wasn't able to add or get any data from this object. Is it probably just a getter.

How can I put some data into `userInfo` object? It has to be part of BE or how?

Comment: I discarded those changes and I can not do it again right now because one of our providers is down I will have to wait a bit and do it again and then I will update this topic

Comment: anyway when i try to add pass like this  ` pass?.userInfo = myDataObject;` it shows this error `Cannot assign to property: 'userInfo' is a get-only property`

Comment: let myDataObject: [String: Any]  = [
      "customerID": "12345"
    ]

Comment: When i put there this:      `pass?.userInfo["customerID"] = "12345"`   ill get this error `Value of optional type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[AnyHashable : Any]'`
 and if i fix that with `?` or '!'       `pass?.userInfo?["customerID"] = "12345"` i will get this error again `Cannot assign through subscript: 'userInfo' is a get-only property`

Comment: Like I said I don't really know this functionality but looking quickly at the documentation there is a reference to [Pass](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/pass) and there userInfo is described as containing json data. So maybe this dictionary should be created and assigned differently than what I am used to. Sorry for leading you down the wrong path.

Comment: no problem I appreciate it